# Can't handle with FirebaseAuthException

Tags: flutter, error-handling

I trying to catch FirebaseAuthException but i can't.
This is the code block

```
TextButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      try {
                        final email = _email.text;
                        final password = _password.text;

                        final userCredential =
                            FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                          email: email,
                          password: password,
                        );
                        print(userCredential);
                      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
                        if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
                          print(e.message);
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    child: Text("Login"),
                  ),
```

and this is the result on the console.

```
I/FirebaseAuth( 2241): Logging in as asdasdhas@gmail.com with empty reCAPTCHA token
E/RecaptchaCallWrapper( 2241): Initial task failed for action RecaptchaAction(action=custom_signInWithPassword)with exception - There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.
E/flutter ( 2241): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_auth/user-not-found] There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.
```

I tried catch the all of Exception but its not working.

**Solved**

inkredusk's answer fixed the problem. Somehow i missed the await word. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are missing the `await` when calling `signInWithEmailAndPassword` method. Can you please try something like this:

```
 try {
  final credential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: emailAddress,
    password: password
  );
 } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
    print('No user found for that email.');
  } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
    print('Wrong password provided for that user.');
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Also, please check in `Firebase` if a user already exists with that `email address`.  Most likely this is happening because the email with you are login/sign-in with does not exist, either you have to register that email by calling `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` method then login/sign-up or correct your email and password. It is important to note that when a user updates their `email, password or resets their password`. Firebase Auth backend revokes their `tokens` requiring that they `reauthenticate` or try to sign in again.